# analysis of BJT PNP type

Tags: transistors

here is the question.

[image]

As the hints states, we assume it is in Active Mode which means V(EB)=0.7 
also, it is given that B=100, therefore, since Ic=B*Ib , gives us Ic=100*Ib
now, I thought it is a good idea to find the relationship between Ie and Ib, so I can apply kvl and substitute one to another so I can come up with one one unknown not two.
Here is what I did 
Ic=(BIe)/(B+1)=Ie/101
now I am stuck and I cannot apply KVL from VEE because Vb is unknown, and I come up with two unknowns.
any ideas or suggestions?  I know I have to find Vb first but how?

Comment: Vb can be specified based upon the base current and the currents entering that node via the 91K and 150K resistors. I91K + Ib + I150K = 0.

Comment: then we come up with two unknowns,

Comment: It sounds like you are getting lost in the forest for the trees. I pointed out part of the process. You still need to apply what you know about the RE, RC, Vbe. Since this definitely looks like homework you need to move forward from the hints provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate.

Start by offsetting the circuit so that the -3V line becomes 0V and the +3V line becomes +6V.  You can return to the plus minus 3V when you are done.

Calculate the Thevenin equivalent voltage at the Q1 base, assuming no base current.  Use that to set the emitter voltage, calculate the current through the emitter resistor.

Use the current through the emitter resistor to calculate the base current and apply that to the Thevenin equivalent voltage at the base.

Recalculate the emitter current.

A couple of rounds of this and you will converge on the answer.  Then you can calculate the current through the collector resistor.  Hint: it's not the same as the emitter current.

This may not be the most elegant way to solve this problem but it is quick to do.

Comment: I did what you said, and I got V(BB)=0.73 which is correct.

Comment: but I still don't understand why ! can you explain this in more detail please ?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to determine the Re equivalent (Ree) as seen by the Base.

With B=100 the Ree seen by the Base is (100 x Re), or 330k.

Replace Re with Ree (330k), add the 0.7v for the emitter diode, calculate the actual Vb and Ib.

Now go back to the original circuit and calculate the rest of the currents and voltages.

(Another simplification would be to create a Thevenin equivalent at the Base with the 91k, 150k, and the two voltages.)

.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNRrcT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: well we did not cover the THV Eq for BJT yet, but I thought of your first way of doing it, to calculate the Ib and Vb, but the what is Ree seen by the base? what does that mean? Ib is going to two branches, how do I find that? I know I have to apply kvl, but how?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand how you got IE=B*Re , that is the formula for Ic not IE, maybe because you disconnected the other part of the circuit you can get that equation?

Comment: You can use the THV Eq to combine the resistors and voltages connected to the base pin.   I didn't list IE, (Ree is the equivalent resistance as seen from the base, since B is the current multiplier, the original Re resistor looks B times larger).  Of course in the real circuit recall that Ie is the total of Ic and Ib.

Comment: In case that Ic was looking like an Ie I edited the font in my circuit, (does that help?)

Answer (score 1):

**strong text**Here is another - straightforward - way to solve the task. You only need Ohms law, which gives you a system of 4 equations with 4 unknowns, which is easy to solve.

Assuming that the current through the 91k resistor is I1 (and the current through the 150k resistor is I1+IB) you can apply Ohms law to the three resistors (base resistors as well as RE). The 4 equations result from:

- VB=f(I1)
- VB=f(I1+IB)
- VE=f(101*IB)
- VE-VB=0.7

Hence, we have 4 equations forthe 4 unknown quantities VB,VE, I1, IB.
Knowing IC=100IB it is no problem to find VC.

**Edit_1** (Remark): The equation are simpler to handle if you change to a single supply voltage of +6V. After calculation of the dc voltages shift all values back (by adding  -3 volts).

**Edit_2**: To simplify the calcualtions you can exploit the **superposition rule** for a circuit with two voltage sources. If you follow the recommendation from above (edit_1) you can calculate the base voltage VB assuming that Veb=VE-VB=0.7 is a dc voltage source. This allowed because of the "substitution theorem" of network theory.

In this case, you have a simple arrangement of three resistors (two of them in parallel) and two driving sources (**6V** and **Veb=0.7V**), which successively can be set to zero. Note that during this calculation the emitter resitor RE must be enlarged by a factor of 101 (because of the emitter current Ie=101*Ib).

**Comment**: Using this method (superposition) I have found the solution within 3 minutes.